# How a Docker app can get files list from a network share path external to Docker?

Tags: docker

I have built Docker image with my ASP.NET Core App , and added this test.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("****TEST: GetFiles");
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Share1\FolderMix\");
        foreach (var f in filePaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"***file: {0}", f);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"***Exception: {0}", x.Message);
        ***Exception: Could not find a part of the path '/app/\\Share1\FolderMix'.
    }
```

It seems the app can brows the internal Docker file system.
How to get files list  from a network share path external to Docker?

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be - 
You need to mount that directory as a volume to your docker container. This way you can access the external files through your docker container.

While running container.

`docker run image  -v <local_dir_path>:<anypath_in_docker_file_system>`

Once you run the container like this, you can access the file

`string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"anypath_in_docker_file_system");`

Comment: The task is: the ASP.NET Web server in Docker is active, it reads network paths  from a database and get file list on the path. I.e. the path should be mounted before Docker container starts or it can be mounted dynamically in the app?